# Differentiate between no selection and selection at index 0 in UITableView

Tags: ios4, uitableview, ipad

I have a UITableView and a UIButton.  When the UIButton is pressed, it prints the text of the UITableViewCell that is selected to the console output.

However, when no selection is made on the UITableView, it defaults to row 0, and displays this text.

How can I determine if there is no selection made, so that I can bring up a UIAlert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try storing the index of the cell when the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method triggers.  That way you can keep track of whether the user has selected a row since the view has been shown

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I was hoping there would just be a simple method call I could have used.